# Good method of implementing factory to convert from one type to another in C#?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I need to convert from types that an XML Serializer built, to a type that Entity Framework can better work with, that has all the relations between the objects.

One such conversion could be, for example:

**FROM**

```
public class ApiAlliance
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("tag")]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("homepage")]
    public string Homepage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("open")]
    public int Open { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("player")]
    public ApiPlayer[] Players { get; set; }
}
```

**TO:**

```
public class Alliance
{
    public int AllianceId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public string Homepage { get; set; }

    public int Open { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    // There is a one-to-many relationship between Universe and Alliance that EF must know about        
    public int UniverseId { get; set; }
    public Universe Universe { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a smart way of doing this, or is it grunt work all the way, creating methods that assigns attributes from one class to another, and so on?

Comment: Try to use `AutoMapper`

Comment: I would use an object-to-object mapper library such as Value Injecter or AutoMapper

Comment: I have never used AutoMapper before, but from what I can tell, it isn't able to do this, or am I wrong?